# Replacing urls with links in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some HTML coming in:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example.com</a>
http://www.example.com
```

In another thread I found this regular expression:

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i;
```

Problem is that it alters the img and the a tags also:

```
<img src="<a href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">http://www.example.com/image.jpg</a>" />
<a href="<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>">Example.com</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
```

Any ideas to handle this swiftly without having to parse the HTML?

Comment: what the regex is suppose to do

Comment: Just make sure it doesn't start and end with quotes `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up traversing the HTML. It's not the fastest solution but works:

```
$(id).find('*').each(function(k,v)
{
    if (v.nodeName == 'A')
    {
    // do stuff 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing html processing using regex is inviting bugs like that, instead try to use the regex with dom processing like

```js
var string = '<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" /> \
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example.com</a>\
http://www.example.com';

var $tmp = $('<div />', {
  html: string
});

var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i;
$tmp.contents().contents().addBack().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {

    $(this).replaceWith(function() {
      return $('<div />', {
        html: this.nodeValue.replace(exp, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
      }).contents()
    })
  }
});

var processed = $tmp.html();
snippet.log(processed)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, yes. I'd just really like to avoid parsing the HTML for each chunk. It will slow things down considerably.

Comment: @user1780407 I think then the question is how accurate you want the result to be.... using string with regex the rules are very rigid to get a correct answer